# Visual Studio 2019 Value does not fall within the expected range when reloading web project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I've just upgraded to VS2019 Pro. I was setting up the new **Solution Filters** feature to allow me to partially load my solutions with only the dependencies for the project I am working on and hit a problem loading (or reloading) an ASP.Net MVC Web Project.

See here: https://youtu.be/u5YauFxb2Ho?t=783

What I did was close my solution and then go to the new Start Page and select Open a project or solution.

Then browse to the *.sln file for the solution and tick the "Do not load projects" checkbox so that the solution opens but no projects are loaded.

When I right clicked the Web Project and chose "Reload Project" I got a "Value does not fall within the expected range" error.

Answer (score 7):

Turns out (after looking in the Output Window - yes, I know) the problem was that VS couldn't launch IIS Express due to a lack of permissions.

Just close and re-**launch VS2019 as Administrator**, re-load the Web Project and IIS Express will start this time and all will be well with your world.

Answer (score 0):

I had to load as admin. Just right click on the visual studio icon and run as admin. That was the only way I could get the form to start.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).